# Как соединить 2 массива объектов возвращаемых сервером?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular

С сервера(nodejs) получаю 2 объекта json вида (в мой клиентский angular 7):

```
obj1 = [{some: "any"}, {some1: "any1"}]
obj2 = [{some2: "any2", some3: "any3"}, {some4: "any4", some5: "any5"}]
```

Как их можно объединить или создать новый третий или что то, это не важно, чтобы получилось такое:

```
obj3 = [{some: "any"}, {some1: "any1"},{some2: "any2", some3: "any3"}, {some4: "any4", some5: "any5"}]
```

Я искал ответ в гугле в тч, на stackoverflow, но concat мне точно не помогает,

```
obj3= [obj1, obj2]
```

Делает ненужный мне вид

```
obj3 = [[...], [...]]
```

Что можно мне сделать?

Comment: 1. `obj1.concat(obj2)` 2. `[...obj1, ...obj2]`

Comment: Я описал, это не работает у меня.
1) Выводит ошибку что obj2 undifined поэтому он не может применить concat
2) Делает не нужный мне вид [ [...], [...] ]

Comment: Что мешает так и писать `obj3= [obj1, obj2]`?

Comment: @MishaSaidov, в вопросе же есть _Делает ненужный мне вид: `obj3 = [[...], [...]]`_

Comment: @Adel Khalitov, в первом комментарии указано решение 2 с оператором `spread`, вы точно этот вариант пробовали?

Comment: А сори, не заметил. Если эти два массива определены, то вы не должны получать ошибку obj2 undefined при конкатенации

Comment: @MishaSaidov, Каким образом я могу определить эти объекты, они принимают значения только any/

Comment: @doigrales, да, он выводит мне вложенные массивы, такой формат данных мне не удобен

Answer (score 2):

Действительно преобразовав возвращаемые данные в тип Array я смог использовать .concat, спасибо @MishaSaidov

Comment: Хотя это не по правилам форума плюсовать такие ответы, но вежливому человеку, который разобрался в проблеме, ИМХО, есть смысл поправить "карму" :)